# Alternative to paired t-test for non independent data

Tags: t-test, independence, neuroimaging

I'm working on a research project where I predict fMRI activity using two separate sets of predictors, X1 and X2. In order to do this, I am fitting a linear regression from each predictor to each voxel in the fMRI separately. I then assess the performance of the regression model on held out data with the out of sample R2 metric. After doing this procedure, I obtain an out of sample R2 metric for each voxel for both of the predictors. So if there are 10,000 voxels, then this procedure yields two 10,000 dimensional vectors consisting of out of sample R2 values, one for X1 and one for X2.

I am interested in comparing the performance of the regression when the predictor is X1 versus when the predictor is X2. Specifically, I would like to know if the mean out of sample R2 across the 10,000 voxels is significantly different between X1 and X2. However, voxels in fMRI are spatially correlated, meaning that my datapoints are not independent. In other words, knowing the out of sample R2 value for a voxel provides information regarding the out of sample R2 value of voxels that are nearby in the brain. Therefore, I believe I cannot apply a method like a paired t-test in this setting. I was wondering if there are any alternative ways to test whether there is a significant difference in the mean between paired observations when the observations are dependent on one another? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you have two groups of R2 values based on different models that you want to compare or do you have two R2 values that you want to compare, using something more appropriate than a t-test?

Comment: Dr. Brian Caffo (JHSPH) is a prolific biostat in this area, you might look at his work.

Comment: You probably need to reframe your question. You have repeated measures, the $R^2$ isn't a reliable measure of model fit - clusters that are oversampled will be overrepresented. On the other hand, if you're trying to generalize the t-test, you're interested in testing a mean difference. So perhaps a repeated measures ANCOVA is what you're after.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I updated my question so that is hopefully more clear. I will look into Dr. Brian Caffo's work and the repeated measures ANCOVA, appreciate the suggestions!